# CSS multiple image positioning

Tags: css

I have two background images, but I cannot display both of them (one of them is invisible).
Another problem is the padding-top for li a element is not working.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="item-102"><a href="/index.php/merchants-shops">Merchants / Shops</a></li>      
    <li class="item-103"><a href="/index.php/contact-us">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

#left #menu ul.menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

#left #menu ul.menu li {
   background: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/menu_fons.png) no-   repeat, url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/bulta_peleka.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: left 0px, 200px 0px;
   width: 294px;
   height: 44px;
   padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#left #menu ul.menu li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;   
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 15px 0 0 17px;
    color: #336699;    
}
```

See full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BWagZ/

The questions are:
1) How to make two background images to appear on button. You can think that the first image is background image for button. But the second image is a small arrow that should be displayed on the right side of the button. Currently this image doesn't appear at all (but it is somwhere there).

2) Why padding-top for li elements are not working? I want text in li element to have top padding in the button.

Comment: And your question is? showing both images next to each other??

Comment: Also, don't just make a link around the "Home". But make it around the whole button.

Comment: This is how Joomla is generating links, I am not sure I know how to add links around all buttons.

Comment: put the link around the whole "li". You do need to restyle the text if you want it to be the same thought.

Comment: See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16770862/1516616) given below. This might fix your problem.

Comment: i'm pretty sure for class you need to use "." instead of "#"...

Comment: Ofcourse css3 solves everything but my answer doesn't contain css3. It is compatilble to css3 not supporting browsers too. Nwaz u guyz r right bt face it i'm not wrong too

Comment: @wazaminator its done correctly in the fiddle. 
Was mine [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16770908/2296407) any help?

Answer (score 2):

You must add a div inside anchor tag for double background and cover full button area
Check out fiddle

HTML

```
<div id="left">

<div id="menu">    
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/"><div>Home</div></a></li><li class="item-102"><a href="/index.php/merchants-shops"><div>Merchants / Shops</div></a></li><li class="item-103"><a href="/index.php/contact-us"><div>Contact us</div></a></li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
margin: 0;
}

#left #menu ul.menu {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
}

#left #menu ul.menu li {
background: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/menu_fons.png) no-repeat;
background-position: left 0px, 200px 0px;
width: 294px;
height: 30px;
padding: 14px 0 5px 0;
}

#left #menu ul.menu li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;   
    font-style: italic;
    color: #336699;
}
#left #menu ul.menu li a div {
    color: #336699;
    background:url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/bulta_peleka.png) no-repeat center right;
    width: 235px;
}
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWagZ/1/)

Comment: OP is using multiple background images, And CSS 3 allows you to do it instead of writing an extra code.

Comment: actually without that extra div your link area is limited to text only

Comment: But in this case, there is no need to add extra markup. Everything can be solved with CSS.

Comment: @edd: Wrong.. If you make `a` a block element using `display: block` then you can achieve it without adding extra div :-)

Comment: @edd: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16770862/1516616) for a demo..

Comment: Ofcourse css3 solves everything but my answer doesn't contain css3. It is compatilble to css3 not supporting browsers too. Nwaz @MrLister and A.K u guyz r right bt face it i'm not wrong too

Comment: @edd: Your answer may be considered as a code tweaking suggestion. But OP is asking why the multiple background are not working actually.

Comment: If no code tweaking is allowed and that is what OP is asking then @A.K is right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the links to have a top-offset in the li element. Then you'd have to set a padding-top in the li element, not the a element, which works for me (Chromium). I don't understand your image-problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achive something like this?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SQS22/)

**Answer 1**:

**Change the orders of the images and positioning accordingly.**

Replace your CSS with the following:

```
#left #menu ul.menu li {
    background-image: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/bulta_peleka.png),    url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/menu_fons.png); 
    background-position: 200px 7px, left 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 294px;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

**Answer 2**:

Add `display: block;` css rule in the following line:

```
 #left #menu ul.menu li a
```

It will make the whole list clickable and your padding will work also.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting some [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) for each **[background](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)**, also when u put the arrow image first you will see both.. now you just have to adjust them.

Is this good enough? http://jsfiddle.net/goodfriend/BWagZ/10/

Answer (score 0):

You should change the order of your backgrounds around.

```
background: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/bulta_peleka.png) no-repeat 200px 0px,
   url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/menu_fons.png) no-repeat left 0px;
```

And the `a` elements you can adjust by giving them a `line-height` property.

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/yFMZf/1

Answer (score 0):

Your method is good. You just have to swapp images between them.
Meaning:

```
background: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/bulta_peleka.png) no-repeat,  url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/menu_fons.png) no-repeat;
```

background-position: 200px 0px, left 0px;